# Restricting bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal

I am using bootstrap modal to showcase my special offers on my site. But this modal pops up, every time the page gets refreshed. How do I restrict this modal to appear only once?

```
<!-- Modal start-->
<div class="container">
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">/* header part */
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">/* Body part */
Some text
</div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">/* Footer part */

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>  
</div>` This is the code used for the modal. What change do i need to make to make the modal pop up just once , rather than appearing on every page refresh??`
</div>  
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myModal").modal();
});
</script>
```

Comment: use a cookie and store, is the popup has showed. check the cookie.

Comment: use cookie or local storage

Comment: By default the document ready function is called every time when a page gets load, that's why the modal pops up every time when the page is refreshed.

Answer (score 2):

**Just remove this:**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myModal").modal();
});
</script>
```

**How you can toggle (hide/show) the modal:**

```
$('#myModal').modal('show')
$('#myModal').modal('toggle')
$('#myModal').modal('hide')
```

**Docs:**

```
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals
```

If you want that the Modal only once appear i suggest jquery-cookies:

```
https://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/
```

**Really simple to use:**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    if( !$.cookie('customer.offers.seen') {
       $("#myModal").modal();
       $.cookie('customer.offers.seen', true);
    }

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the HTML5 **sessionStorage** which stores the data for only one session. Basically it lives with the browser tab. 
If the user refresh it still there but if they close the tab its removed.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        if (sessionStorage.getItem("loaded") === null) {
          sessionStorage.setItem("loaded", "loaded");
          $("#myModal").modal();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

By using **cookie** try the following

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myModal").modal();
});
</script>
```

into

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var pop_up_show = $.cookie("pop_up_show"); 
    if(typeof pop_up_show != "undefined" && pop_up_show == "1"){

    }else{
        $.cookie("pop_up_show", "1");
        $("#myModal").modal();      
    }

});
</script>
```